# Why did Yi-kyung's child turn out the way she did?

Tags: sweet-home

In the second season of *Sweet Home*, Seo Yi-kyung gives birth to a child that

> appears to be some type of unique half-monster, like Hyun-su. This appears to happen after an unusually rapid pregnancy, and the child ages in a very unusual manner.

Why was Yi-kyung's child born this way? Are all children being born this way after the beginning of the monster phenomenon? Is it actually because her own negative emotions converted her child into a half-monster during the pregnancy, as she seems to believe? Because her husband was a monster (even though he must have transformed after they conceived)?